# Need to prefer file ownership while uploading through scp

Tags: scp

I have been tring to upload a file through a normal user to the Amazon Gnu/Linux server, but file owner is not preferring after a successful upload.

File ownership is taken from the directory, not from the user which I have used to move the file.

Example:

```
scp -i xxx.pem filename surya@publicipaddress:/home/surya

ls -lh filename 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user 1.7K Dec 24 11:30 filename
```

Here, After uploading a file, the ownership should be `surya` as I have used `surya` user to upload the file.

Comment: What meaning are you attaching to “Preferring”? Are those two commands on the **same** machine?

Comment: Is your "ls" output from running ls on the remote system, or the local system? Did "filename" already exist on the remote system before you ran scp?

Comment: There may be something in the `sshd_config` that is forcing ownership change, or perhaps a `setuid` and `setgid` bit is set on a directory above the one you are uploading to (this will also force ownership change).

Comment: What is the output of `ssh -i xxx.pem sutya@publicipaddress ls -lnd  . filename` ? Unix stores the ownership of a file as a numeric value, and `ls` consults things like the password file to translate them to names. If `ec2-user` and `surya` have the same number then as far as file ownership is concerned they are the same user (they can have different passwords etc)

Answer (score 0):

The `scp` command doesn't preserve owner and group for copied files.
For this purpose you can use the next commands:

1. `rsync` command with `--owner (or -o)` and `--group(or -g)` options.
   From `man`:
   `-o, --owner         preserve owner (super-user only)
   -g, --group          preserve group`
2. or `tar` coomand:
   `tar --owner=user --group=user -cpf - ./* | ssh -l user dest_server \
   'tar xpf - -C /path/to/folder'`

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, it's not about *preserving* ownership, but that the file is *created* as owned by the remote `ec2-user` (no matter who the local owner is), even when the remote user is `surya`, and not `ec2-user`. Which likely means something on the remote host is enforcing this, whatever it is. Which likely means `rsync` will run into the same enforcement.